# Detach microphone from sinch video call

Tags: android, microphone, sinch

While user call using sinch video call, I need microphone to record what he said then translate. But I can't use microphone.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The microphone can only be used by one process at a time. You can check if the Sinch video call is occupying the microphone using the snipped below

```
public static boolean checkIfMicrophoneIsBusy(Context ctx){
    AudioRecord audio = null;
    boolean ready = true;
    try{
        int baseSampleRate = 44100;
        int channel = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
        int format = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        int buffSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(baseSampleRate, channel, format );
        audio = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, baseSampleRate, channel, format, buffSize );
        audio.startRecording();
        short buffer[] = new short[buffSize];
        int audioStatus = audio.read(buffer, 0, buffSize);

        if(audioStatus == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION || audioStatus == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED /* For Android 6.0 */)
            ready = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ready = false;
    }
    finally {
        try{
            audio.release();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    return ready;
}
```

Comment: It return false. the sinch video call hold the micro. Is there anyway to get micro for recording?

Comment: Hi, no we need it, so its not possible, sorry